# Decompose and interpret results of git branch -rvv

Tags: bash, git, version-control

What specific commands do I use to decompose the columns that are returned by the following `git branch` command?

```
git branch -rvv  | grep "Merge pull request" | grep "$fromCurrentRepoTo"
```

Also, what is each column in the results in addition to simply giving the command for returning only the individual column's value?

The [official documentation at this link](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) states that, when the `-vv` flag is given, the results will:

> show sha1 and commit subject line for each head, along with relationship to upstream branch (if any), as well as the name of the upstream branch.

This means that the following 4 columns would be included in the results:

```
sha1 
commit subject line
relationship to upstream branch (if any)
name of the upstream branch
```

But the results below seem to include 6 columns instead of just the above-listed 4 columns.

To help decompose the answer to this 2-part OP, I have included the complete list of commands and the complete terminal output.

### Complete script

For reference, the complete sequence of commands leading up to the above command is as follows:

```
echo "About to currentRepo=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"
currentRepo=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
echo "about to echo currentRepo"
echo $currentRepo
fromVar="from "
toVar=" to"
fromCurrentRepoTo="$fromVar$currentRepo$toVar"
echo "about to echo fromCurrentRepoTo"
echo $fromCurrentRepoTo
echo "About to git branch -rvv  | grep 'Merge pull request' | grep fromCurrentRepoTo"
git branch -rvv  | grep "Merge pull request" | grep "$fromCurrentRepoTo"
echo "----------------------------------"  
echo "About to git branch -rvv"
git branch -rvv
```

### Terminal output

When the above commands are run, the following is output into the console:

```
build   03-Apr-2018 11:08:52    About to currentRepo=Issue_Example
build   03-Apr-2018 11:08:52    about to echo currentRepo
build   03-Apr-2018 11:08:52    Issue_Example
build   03-Apr-2018 11:08:52    about to echo fromCurrentRepoTo
build   03-Apr-2018 11:08:52    from Issue_Example to
build   03-Apr-2018 11:08:52    About to git branch -rvv  | grep 'Merge pull request' | grep fromCurrentRepoTo
build   03-Apr-2018 11:08:52      origin/feature/Feature_Version_Example 37d71e5 Merge pull request #2 in PCFPT/scriptsforexamples from Issue_Example to feature/Feature_Version_Example
build   03-Apr-2018 12:56:04    ----------------------------------
build   03-Apr-2018 12:56:04    About to git branch -rvv
build   03-Apr-2018 12:56:04      origin/HEAD                            -> origin/master
build   03-Apr-2018 12:56:04      origin/Issue_Example                   6f8346a who is the dirty rat now?
build   03-Apr-2018 12:56:04      origin/feature/Feature_Version_Example 37d71e5 Merge pull request #2 in PCFPT/scriptsforexamples from Issue_Example to feature/Feature_Version_Example
build   03-Apr-2018 12:56:04      origin/master                          cf60eb7 Initial Commit
build   03-Apr-2018 12:56:04    ----------------------------------
```

### Restating the question

The two parts of the question can be re-stated as follows including the actual data returned in the terminal output above:

1. What are each of these columns? (guesses are in parentheses below)
2. What specific syntax do I need in order to extract each column's value into a separate variable?

   1. origin/feature/Feature_Version_Example
   2. 37d71e5 (sha1 of most recent commit)
   3. Merge pull request #2 (subject line of commit?)
   4. PCFPT/scriptsforexamples  (remote project and repository)
   5. Issue_Example
   6. feature/Feature_Version_Example

I am including the `bash` tag because this is on a CentOS server with some `bash` commands shown above.

Comment: Hi CodeMed! I notice you are fond of using the quote block device in your posts. I agree this can be handy, but it is not actually a general highlighter. It's purpose mirrors that of the `<blockquote>` in HTML - it is for quotes i.e. something said in a written resource or from a person. It helps distinguish what material in your post is in your own voice and that which is in someone else's. If you can use quote blocks in that fashion, that'd be great, as it would save volunteer editors some work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The output of `git branch -vv` and `git branch -rvv` (equal to `git branch -vv -r`) are different.

- For `git branch -vv`, it will return four columns similar as you mentioned (list based on local branches):

  ```
  Column 1: local branch name
  Column 2: sha-1 value
  Column 3: related tracking branch name if has. Else the column is empty
  Column 4: commit (for the sha-1 value as column 2 list) message
  ```
- For `git branch -rvv`, it will return **three columns** (list based on tracking branches):

  ```
  Column 1: tracking branch name
  Column 2: sha-1 value
  Column 3: commit (for the sha-1 value as column 2 list) message
  ```

So the command `git branch -rvv  | grep "Merge pull request" | grep "$fromCurrentRepoTo"` you used returns with three columns as below:

```
Column 1: origin/feature/Feature_Version_Example
Column 2: 37d71e5
Column 3: Merge pull request #2 in PCFPT/scriptsforexamples from Issue_Example to feature/Feature_Version_Example
```

To Get the tracking branch name  (column 1) or sha-1 value (column 2), you can split the outpy string by blank space (not available for commit message since there usually has blank spaces in commit message):

```
st=$(git branch -rvv |grep "Merge pull request" | grep "$fromCurrentRepoTo")
IFS=' '
for t in $st; do
  echo $t
done
```

To get the commit message (column 3) from the commit, you can use the command:

```
git show -s --format=%s <sha-1 value>
```

Comment: Thank you very much and +1 for this high quality answer.  I hope to examine it more closely when I return to that section of the project that inspired this inquiry.  The reason I have not marked it as accepted yet is that I will have to turn each of the columns into a usable variable in order to integrate your suggestions.  I am hoping to resolve this with a block of code that enables me to print out each column individually as if I have `object1.property1`, `object1.property2`, and `object1.property3`, etc. I can do that easily, but I want to complete that before I mark this as accepted.

Comment: Sure, you can mark the answer afterring finishing the works. And if there have other problems during your inquiry, feel free let me know :)